# Printing a Form includes data grid and axmapcontrol

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-engine, vb.net

I have created a windows form with some controls in it like data grid and axmapcontrol, it seems that printform cannot print the content of the axmapcontrol. I need to create a table of data and a map referencing the table data, like printing map and attribute table in one page.

I'm looking for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the PageLayout control which gives you a lot of control over the layout of the page. Check out the the [samples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Using_the_PageLayoutControl/000100000497000000/).